# download file from my server directory using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, download

please bellow code for understanding. i am using html and javascript in my code i want to download file from my server directory usings javascript codding, for example when i click on download button then i want one file on click event of javascript.

```
{function downloadfile(path){
 alert(path);
}
<a href="#" onclick="downloadfile('uploaded/document/<?=$row['filelocation'];?>')">DOWNLOAD</a>}
```

Comment: I've never been JavaScript fishing before.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this ?

```
window.open(URL, '_self');
```

URL is the absolute URL of the file you want to download.

Comment: not now but i am trying this code

Comment: this code is not working, i want same like downloading any file, image file suddenly open in window

Comment: are you understand my question? if yes then why visitors are given me two bed reviews?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot force-download a file via JavaScript if that is what you are looking for. You can open the file in a new window, but in my opinion the proper way to do this is to avoid JavaScript and just link to a PHP file which forces download, that way the browser won't show the page because it is downloading a file.

That would be something among the lines of:

**HTML / PHP**

```
<a href="download.php?file=uploaded/document/<?=$row['filelocation'];?>">DOWNLOAD</a>
```

**PHP Script (download.php)** - I got parts of this code from http://davidwalsh.name/php-force-download

```
<?php
// grab the requested file's name
$file_name = urldecode($_GET['file']);

// make sure it's a file before doing anything!
if(is_file($file_name)) {
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file_name).'"');
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file_name));    // provide file size

    readfile($file_name);       // push it out
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi Terwanerik i am getting this error : Windows Photo Viewer can' open this picture because either Photo Viewer doesn't support this file format, or you don't have the latest updates to Photo Viewer.

Comment: when i am open this file using window default picture viewer.

Comment: What kind of image is it? jpeg, png, gif?

Comment: i am using jpeg image

Comment: It should work fine then, try removing jpeg and jpg from the $mime switch on the file extension like so: `switch(strtolower(substr(strrchr($file_name, '.'), 1))) {
        case 'pdf': $mime = 'application/pdf'; break;
        case 'zip': $mime = 'application/zip'; break;
        case 'jpeg':
        case 'jpg': $mime = 'image/jpg'; break;
        default: $mime = 'application/force-download';
    }`

Comment: this code is also not working

Comment: Alright i removed some functionality from the download.php script and edited my answer.

Comment: this is not working bro...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65769/discussion-between-terwanerik-and-chetan-ghadiya).

Answer (score 1):

the destination of your link has a PHP file with this source:

```
// File: download.php

$filename = $_GET['path'];

header('Content-type: Application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$nome_file');
header('Content-Description: My Download :)');
header('Content-Length: '. filesize($filename) );
readfile($filename);
```

Your Javascript function:

```
function downloadfile(path){
    window.open('download.php?path='+path, '_blank');
}
```

Best regards,
Kevin